# create a fake transparent effect

Tags: css, sass

I have a bunch of div (.field) inside each is a label with two children, an input text that has a black border, and a span that has a absolute position over the input text. I use the span as a "placeholder":

```
<div className="field">
   <label>
      <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="" />
      <span>Post Title</span>
   </label>
</div>
```

When the input text is focused, or the placeholder is not shown the span jumps to the top of the label and its position is on the border of the input text. This has already been coded. The issue I am having is that my background for my main div the one the encompasses all the .field div's is:

```
                    background-color: #60dfcd;
                    background-image: linear-gradient(315deg, #60dfcd40 0%, #1e99fe40 74%);
```

When the span hovers over the border of the input text, I need it to have a background that will match with the colour of the div in that specific location as if to give it a transparent effect, if I use the same code for div's background you can clearly see that the span has a background, and the fake transparent effect does not appear.

My question is how do I give the span a background colour that matches the background of the main div depending on where it is. Reason I cannot use a transparent background is because the span, hovers over the border of the input so with a transparent background it will not hide the border.

also here is the code for my styling:

```
.form{
   border-radius: 0!important;
   background-color: #60dfcd;
   background-image: linear-gradient(315deg, #60dfcd40 0%, #1e99fe40 74%);
   color: $darkTextColour;

   .field{
      color: $darkTextColour;
      padding: 0px;
      margin: 20px 0px;
      width: 100%;
            
      label {
         position: relative;
         width: 100%;
                
         span {
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            padding: 4px 7px;
            margin: 7px;
            white-space: nowrap;
            transform: translate(0, 0);
            transform-origin: 0 0;
            transition: transform 120ms ease-in;
         }
         input,
         textarea,
         select{
            position: relative;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            border: 1px solid #000;
            padding: 15px 7px;
            background: transparent;
                    
            &:focus,
            &:not(:placeholder-shown) {

               & + span {
                  transform: translate(.25rem, -65%) scale(.8);
                  color: $secondaryColour;
                  background-color: #60dfcd;
                  background-image: linear-gradient(315deg, #60dfcd40 0%, #1e99fe40 74%);
               }
            }
         }
         select{
            padding: 11.75px 7px!important;
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I don't know if it is of importance, but I am using React, with scss